# Squid Proxy with Authentication Not Returning A Response

Tags: authentication, proxy, squid

I am trying to set up a proxy server using Squid that interfaces with an outside server for authentication. We have configured and set up Squid and a program to carry out the authentication, but when we attempt to test it we get no response - not an error or an OK response or anything at all.

We haven't tested proper authentication with the outside server, but we have a list of usernames on file that we are testing with that should return a response. We have tested the authentication program with those servers on commandline on the server, and it returns the correct response, so we suspect that the problem is with the squid.conf file, but we're almost sure that this is the correct configuration.

Here is the relevant squid.conf;

```
auth_param basic program /path/to/AuthClient/dist/build/AuthClient/AuthClient
auth_param basic realm proxy

acl ip1 src Address1 #ommitting the actual IP addresses but these are the correct ones.
acl ip2 src Address2    
acl authdetails proxy_auth REQUIRED

acl Safe_ports port 1-65535

http_access !Safe_ports
http_access allow authdetails ip2

http_access deny all

http_port proxy.ip.address.here:3128

# Some code below to enable inserting banners into the users websites - probably not relevant but I'm not sure so I left it in.
icap_enable on

icap_service service_req reqmod_precache bypass=1 icap://127.0.0.1:1344/request
adaptation_access service_req allow all

icap_service service_resp respmod_precache bypass=0 icap://127.0.0.1:1344/response
adaptation_access service_resp allow all
```

For reference, here is the main part of Authclient, which is written in Haskell, which should be handling authentication. We think the issue is with the squid.config, but it is included just in case.

```
Module Main where

import Control.Applicative

import System.Environment
import System.IO

import Control.Monad

getPeople = map words . lines <$> getContents

main = getPeople >>= authUsers

authUsers :: [[String]] -> IO ()
authUsers ([user,pass]:xs) = do
    res <-  if user `elem` userlist then return "OK" else return "ERR" 
    appendFile "/tmp/authtest" ("Got request from " ++ user ++" with " ++ res ++"\n")
    putStrLn res
    authUsers xs
authUsers (_:xs) = putStrLn "ERR" >> authUsers xs
authUsers _ = return ()
userlist = #There is a userlist here.
```

We aren't sure what is going wrong, though it is probably in the squid.conf. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please check and confirm any request from squid for authentication is hitting your custom authentication pgm. When using basic authentication, the username and password will be base64 encoded and in your authentication program, you have to handle it(I dont know Haskell, hence i cant understand whether you have handled that in your authentication program)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm not sure how to check if the auth request is hitting the authentication pgm. access.log just has a few instances of TCP_DENIED/407.
Is my reading correct that the base64 encoding is a potential separate issue to the auth request not hitting the authentication pgm? We aren't handling the base64 in our decoding to the best of my knowledge.